# Task Still Run When Already Do Task Cancel

Tags: c#, task

This is Task Code

```
public async Task Demo(int row_index, CancellationToken token)
        {
            Task t1 =  Task.Run(() =>
            {
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            ChromeDriverService chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
            chromeDriverService.SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation = true;
            chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
            this.chrome[row_index] = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, chromeOptions);
            this.chrome[row_index].Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(59.0);
            Dologin(row_index);
            //Lay Ten Fb
            chrome[row_index].Url = "https://facebook.com/profile";
            var conchim = chrome[row_index].FindElementByCssSelector("#fb-timeline-cover-name > a");
            this.dataGridView1.Rows[row_index].Cells["trangthai"].Value = "Tiến Hành Lấy Tên Facebook";
            foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                string value1 = r.Cells[0].Value.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
                if (value1 == tkfacebook)
                {
                    r.Cells[4].Value = conchim.Text;
                    break;
                }
            }
            },token);
        }
```

This is Code Run Task And Cancel Task.

```
CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken token;
public async void HandleValue(DataGridViewCell cell, int row_index)
{
    switch (cell.Value.ToString())
    {
        case "Bắt đầu":
            bool flag7 = Convert.ToInt32(this.txtClickStart.Value) > Convert.ToInt32(this.txtClickEnd.Value);
            if (radioButton1.Checked && !flag7)
            {
                cell.Value = "Kết Thúc";
                token = source.Token;
                await Demo(row_index,token);
            }
            if (flag7)
            {
                this.dataGridView1.Rows[row_index].Cells["trangthai"].Value = "Cài đặt thời gian  không đúng";
                MessageBox.Show(new Form
                {
                    TopMost = true
                }, "Cài đặt thời gian  không đúng, hãy cài đặt lại!", "Lỗi", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
                return;
            }
            bool flag3 = !radioButton1.Checked || !radioButton1.Checked && !radioButton2.Checked;
            if (flag3)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Vui Lòng Chọn Trình Duyệt Để Bắt Đầu Chạy");
            }
            break;
        case "Kết Thúc":
            source.Cancel();
             chrome[row_index].Quit();
            cell.Value = "Bắt đầu";
            this.dataGridView1.Rows[row_index].Cells["trangthai"].Value = "Bạn đã chọn kết thúc làm việc";
            break;
    }
}
```

Thread is not working so i do Task . But it still Run when i already Do Task Cancel. ...............

```
source.Cancel();
```

Make Post Longger to Avablie To Post . Dont Care this Rows ..dfsdfsdfsddfsddsadasdsadasdsadasdasdassdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdadda

Comment: Inside your task code you have to check the token for cancellation - it is not done by some kind of magic ;o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aim to cancel the execution of logic, then you need to check IsCancellationRequested flag.

```
while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
{
 //whatever logic you want run should be placed here. This logic won't be
 //executed after you call Cancel()
}
```

Above logic will continue to execute your logic until you called `Cancel()` on token source. You can find some example [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads#code-example) and [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation).

Comment: @Phia123Eto, Which part of your Demo method that you expect to run until you call token source cancel ?

Comment: Did you look at the example link ?

Comment: OK i will now :v i forgot sorry

Comment: @Phia123Eto, I have added one more which shows how this is implemented in Task

Answer (score 0):

Your Code for Demo should include a check on the cancelation-Token. Try something like this:

```
Task t1 =  Task.Run(() =>
        {
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            ChromeDriverService chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
            chromeDriverService.SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation = true;
            chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
            this.chrome[row_index] = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, chromeOptions);
            this.chrome[row_index].Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(59.0);
            Dologin(row_index);
            //Lay Ten Fb
            chrome[row_index].Url = "https://facebook.com/profile";
            var conchim = chrome[row_index].FindElementByCssSelector("#fb-timeline-cover-name > a");
            this.dataGridView1.Rows[row_index].Cells["trangthai"].Value = "Tiến Hành Lấy Tên Facebook";
            foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Task was cancelled by user.");
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }

                string value1 = r.Cells[0].Value.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
                if (value1 == tkfacebook)
                {
                    r.Cells[4].Value = conchim.Text;
                    break;
                }
            }
        },token);
```

Please also refer the example here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.iscancellationrequested?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: The Code Is Longger Than I put In Here . SO where should i put                 if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Task was cancelled by user.");
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }

Comment: Because cant post long code . So i delet some . And just put about 60% of code Of DEMO

Comment: Actually this code must be checked while executing the task. as I found an for-each-loop I would check it there to ensure, that the code is canceled.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/KcyzG88Y full code here . Can you tell me why should i put it in

Comment: You have to identify all necessary positions. 
I would recommand to do this before any loop (if you want the loop to be finshed) and also in every loop (in case you want to stop immeditaly)